# Show Hello World in NetBeans 8.2 Spring MVC 4.0.1

Tags: spring-mvc, netbeans-8.2

I am newbie to Java & MVC. I am using Netbeans IDE 8.2, Spring MVC 4.0.1 Framework and GlashFish Server 4.1.1

I just created a new web application with everything default and created a view hello.jsp and controller HelloController.Java.

I am following some instructions on [this](https://sites.google.com/site/springmvcnetbeans/step-by-step#part1) site

Following is my directory/project structure
[Project Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72OYP.png)

**Here is my dispatch web.xml file**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Here is my springapp-servlet.xml file**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

       <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet --> 
<!--  <bean name="/hello.htm" class="springapp.web.HelloController" /> -->
  
</beans>
```

Here is my Hello Controller file

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package springapp.web;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory; 
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 *
 * @author marsh
 */
public class HelloController {
     protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException { 
        logger.info("Returning hello view"); 
        return new ModelAndView("hello.jsp");
    } 
}
```

***All I wanted is to display the hello.jsp on deploying it. Please assist.***

Answer (score 0):

when you are using spring 4.x you have to use annotations, then you just have to add @Controller at the begining of your method